# MVC Bootstrap 3.0 - String data from database not breaking lines in any container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a database containing a string, instructions to a recipe. - I an using a TextAreaFor as input box, where i can break lines to format it pretty.

The data is stored in the database as a long string, there are no breakline characters in the database as i can see in the Server Explorer. But when i copy it out from the database table, and into notepad++ it breaks up just fine, as i would expect it to.

My problem is then, how do i make it break in my view?
I have tried every container i could think off, but it's just showed as one long string.

Answer (score 1):

By default new lines in your text are not respected by Html processor. 
You can

- Use CSS(This will work for IE 8+) - [`white-space: pre-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

  `<p style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.VeryLongString</p>`
- Use C# to replace new line with `<br />` if you have to support ancient browsers:
  `@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.VeryLongString).Replace("\n", "<br />"))`